# What compression type should we choose to unzip .gz files using Copy activity on ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF Copy Activity to unzip .gz files I have on my ADLS Gen2, which compression type should we choose from the drop-down list below? All of them failed to work for me.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: To unzip .gz files using ADF Copy Activity, you should choose gzip as the compression type from the drop-down list.

Comment: If you are unzipping, be sure that only the Source has GZip compression selected. The Sink should have compression type set to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @**Joel Cochran**'s comment.

To Unzip the file of `.gz` type, give `gzip` for the **Compression type** in the source dataset of the copy activity.

[image]

And in sink dataset, give the target location and Compression type as **None**.

[image]

**My Unzipped files in target location after copy activity execution:**

[image]